# looking up a m2m relationship

Tags: python, django, filter

Given the model below, How can i find objects who's "days" field has has today.  Basically, show me the jobs who have a certain day set.  'Wed' for example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**model.py**

```
class Day(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s"%(self.day)

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    ...
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    days = models.ManyToManyField(Day)
```

**view.py**

```
today = datetime.date.today()
dayofweek = today.strftime("%a")
DAY = Day.objects.get(day=dayofweek)

#not sure how i would 'filter' this to get the results i need
```

Answer (score 2):

`Job.objects.filter(days=DAY)` is correct.

Comment: ah! it does indeed work.  Thanks!  Bonus points, is it possible to have a compound filter?  say i wanted to filter all jobs whos days were today and who's 'start' time is now.  Do i have to just write two filters?